# Is there a way to tell shell commands are available in a docker image?

Tags: docker

I'm using the [node docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) as a container for my build pipelines.

An issue I frequently run into is that a binary that I expect to exist, doesn't and I have to wait for it fail in the build pipeline. The `zip` command is one such example.

I can run the docker image on my local machine and ssh in to test commands.

Is there a way to summarise what commands are available for a given image?

Comment: I find with images that include many steps, it's often easier to run the base image interactively and run through the commands rather that perform trial and error via full docker build.  The latter can be time consuming especially if you are installing all packages up front as the first step as you may not benefit from layer caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to summarise what commands are available for a given image?

You could look at the contents of `/bin`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=ls node /bin
```

or `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=ls node /usr/local/bin
```

etc...

Comment: Yip fair enough.

Comment: (You should usually be able to run `docker run --rm -it node ls /bin`, putting the entire command after the image name; this works with the standard Docker Hub images.  For your own images prefer setting the main command with `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT` to have the simpler syntax available.)

Comment: @DavidMaze that isn't always guaranteed to work though, right? Overwriting the entrypoint is more reliable